# How to push and run a spring-batch application on Bluemix?

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-cloud, spring-batch, cloud-foundry

I have created a spring batch application in spring boot to perform a daily activity for processing data in batch. I am also able to build and create an uber-jar that has all the dependencies in it. How do I push this jar file as a batch application (not as a web application) and how do I invoke the application to start from the command line if possible?

Answer (score 0):

For cloud foundry applications without the web interface, you can run them with:

```
---
  ...
  no-route: true
```

This will disable the web interface - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#no-route

You may also want to set the health check to process:

```
---
  ...
  health-check-type: process
```

This will monitor the exit status of your application.  Note that this will monitor the process your java process.  If it stops (e.g. batch job application finishes), cloud foundry will try to restart it - https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/healthchecks.html.  This assumes that you want your application to run continuously.

You will probably want to check the java build pack for methods for running your jar - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/README.md.

I think you will want to deploy using the [Java Main method](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/example-java_main.md), which runs Java applications with a main() method provided that they are packaged as self-executable JARs.  Cloud foundry will automatically run the main() method.